# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un botón para que un input pueda abrir una url en una nueva pestaña?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

¿Cómo puedo hacer un botón para que un input `type="text"` pueda abrir url en una nueva pestaña?. Lo he intentado de esta manera, pero no me ha funcionado:

```html
<form action="" method="get" target="_blank">

<input type="text" name="q" value="" size="40"/>

 <INPUT type=submit value="Abrir" />

</form>
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué URL? ¿Por qué tiene que ser desde un `input` dentro de un `form`? Si pones la URL en al atributo `action` del `form` la misma se abrirá, y enviarás los datos que hayas llenado en el `form`. ¿No es más bien eso lo que quieres?

Answer (score 3):

El target="_blank" del form no hace nada. A parte, necesitas un boton, no un input.
Para usar un target="_blank" en un formulario, debes usar el parametro formtarget="_blank"
Este es el codigo que te propongo:

```
<form action="" method="get">

    <input type="text" name="q" value="" size="40" />

    <button type="submit" value="abrir" formtarget="_blank">Abrir</button>

</form>
```

Un saludo, espero que te ayude

Answer (score 3):

necesitaras utilizar javascript para hacer lo que quieres. Te comparto mi código.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function abrir(){
                let url = document.getElementById("url").value;
                console.log(url);
                window.open("http://" + url, '_blank');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="url" type="text">
        <button onclick="abrir()">abrir</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, es una buena manera de hacerlo.